How to resolve setFormControlValue issue in angular
I am getting below the error in the test case error in my angular 16 application.

Error: NG0302: The pipe 'setFormControlValue' could not be found in the 'AppComponent' component. Verify that it is declared or imported in this module. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302

How to resolve this issue?
app.component.ts:
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public expanded = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isToggle();
  }

  isToggle() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
}

app.component.spec.ts:
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 

describe('LimiterMetadataValuesComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
 
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({})]
       
    }).compileComponents(); 
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should set isExpanded to false when toggle is called with false', () => { 
    component.isToggle(false); 
    expect(component.expanded).toBeFalse();
  });

  it('should set isExpanded to false when toggle is called with true', () => { 
    component.isToggle(true); 
    expect(component.expanded).toBeTrue();
  });
 
});

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rshhdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
How to resolve that setFormControlValue issue
